# C++ creating a string from char array elements?

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a char array which is VERY large and I iterate through the array. I look for patterns with logic such as:

```
if (array[n] == 'x' and array[n+1] == 'y' and array[n+2] == 'z')
{
    mystring = array[n+4] + array[n+5];
}
```

if array[n+4] is '4' and array[n+5] is '5' then mystring = "45"

However, mystring is always "", what am I doing wrong? I don't want to use substring as the array is too large. I just want to cast the chars to strings and then append to mystring.

Comment: Have you considered using streams?

Comment: @Borgleader `myString = std::string(array[n + 4]) + array[n + 5]` for an even shorter variant.

Comment: @H2CO3 `std::string mystring = std::string(1,array[i + 4]) + array[i + 5];` as none of the constructor takes just `char`

Comment: `array[n+4] + array[n+5]` doesn't do what you think it does. It takes the two characters as ASCII values and adds them together to create a new single character. It doesn't create a new string with the two characters concatenated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking for a consecutive `"xyz"` occurrence , why not simply use `std::string` ?

```
std::string s(array);

size_t i =s.find("xyz");
if(i!=std::string::npos && i+5 <= s.size())
{
    std::string mystring = std::string(1,array[i + 4]) + array[i + 5];
    std::cout<<mystring;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest so use assign(const char*, len);
no copy constructor is involved

```
if (array[n] == 'x' and array[n+1] == 'y' and array[n+2] == 'z')
{
   mystring.assign(array + n + 4, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast chars to ints and vice versa because they are basic language types. Strings are implemented as a class so you need to invoke the string constructor for both chars then concatenation the two resulting strings into mystring

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `std::string` in the first place, as suggested by @P0W (which is a good suggestion), then there is another alternative to do this conversion that does not involve string constructor (I think the solution using string constructor is a great one, but knowing different approaches can give you more flexibility), but relies on std::string::append.

```
int main ()
{
    // create char
    char *str1 = new char[6];
    strcpy( str1,"hello ");
    char *str2 = new char[5];
    strcpy(str2, "world" );

    // use of append to convert to a string
    std::string mystring;
    mystring.append(str1);
    mystring.append(str2);
    std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

Check the `std::string::append` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/), and you will also see that one of the overloading of this functions is `string& append (const char* s, size_t n)`, which means you can convert just subset of char arrays, as you request it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this involves extracting chars from a large array of chars and "gluing them" together to create a string?

Comment: mystring.append(array[n+4]); mystring.append(array[n+5]) or mystring.append(array[n+4], 2)

Answer (score 0):

Adding characters strings doesn't work like that in C++. The easier way to do this is to create a `stringstream` and add the characters to the string with the << operator, then recover a string from it using the `str()` method.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = {'a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' };
    stringstream linestream;
    linestream << a[0] << a[1];
    cout << linestream.str() << endl; // Prints ad
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::string::append mimic "adding characters" and it is simpler than stringstream, no?